# erlang "illegal guard expression" while using function in Guards

Tags: erlang

I have the following code. I am checking 3 conditions. You can see for the first condition I stored the output of `xml:get_tag_attr_s(...)` in a variable and then used the variable within the if block. My problem is I get error `illegal guard expression`, if I try to do the above process in one line like I did for the other two conditions.

Also, I am getting `variable '_' is unbound` from the default condition. It supposed to be the same thing.

Can somebody please explain the issue?

```
validate_xmpp(Packet) ->
      Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s(list_to_binary("type"), Packet),
      if
          (Type /= <<"chat">> ->
              {error, "Message type is not chat"};
          xml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, list_to_binary("body")}, cdata]) /= <<"">> ->
              {error, "No or empty body"};
          exml_query:path(Packet, [{element,<<"received">>},{attr,<<"xmlns">>}]) == <<"urn:xmpp:receipts">> ->
              {error, "delivery-receipts should be ignored"};
          _->
              {ok, xml:get_tag_attr_s(list_to_binary("from"), Packet)}
      end.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About the usage of "if" in Erlang language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546371/about-the-usage-of-if-in-erlang-language)

Comment: And perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861347/why-comparing-function-results-is-an-illegal-guard-exception-in-erlang) as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Erlang allows only these to be guards:

- The atom `true`
- Other constants (terms and bound variables), all regarded as false
- Calls to the BIFs (*built-in functions*) specified in table Type Test BIFs
- [Term comparisons](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79827)
- [Arithmetic expressions](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#arithmetic-expressions)
- [Boolean expressions](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#boolean-expressions)
- [Short-circuit expressions (`andalso` and `orelse`)](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#short-circuit-expressions)

For more info take a look http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id83606

Instead of `_` use `true`.  You cannot use `_` in `if`, only in `case` statements, and also take a look at the [docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79827).

Comment: Thanks! what about the variable '_' is unbound error I am getting ?

Answer (score 3):

```
isPrime(A,B) when B>math:sqrt(A) -> true;
```

That results in an illegal guard error.

On a first reading, it looks like the guard contains a "term comparison":

```
>
```

and an "arithmetic expression":

```
math:sqrt(A)
```

Futhermore, if you play around with the code, you will see that the guard:

```
B > A+2
```

***is*** legal.  So what's the difference between the "arithmetic expression" `math:sqrt(A)` and `A+2`?

The [Erlang docs](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#arithmetic-expressions) define an "arithmetic expression" as: `

```
+   
- 
*
/
div
rem
bnot
band
bor
bxor
bsl
bsr
```

Notably, `math:sqrt()` is not in the list of "arithmetic expressions".  Therefore, `math:sqrt(A)` is a "function call" rather than an "arithmetic expression", and you can only call a certain limited number of functions in a guard, namely the "type test BIF's" listed [here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#guard-sequences), such as:

```
is_integer/1
is_float/1
is_binary/1
is_list/1
is_map/1
is_function/1
etc.
```